# Crawlling html and save json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im crawlling a html page, and is working fine but im having a issue, when im looping a rows from a table, and saving it in a json file, when finishing the loop instead of having 7 records i get the one 1 record and the last one from the loop.

My code:

```
finalResult[date] = {};

$(this).find('tbody tr').each(function (i, el) {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td')
  var counter = i +1;

  $tds.each(function(index, element){

    var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());

    if($th.text() != ""){
      var temp = { [counter] : $(this).text()};
      finalResult[date][$th.text()] = { ...temp };
    }
  });
});
```

Im getting this result:

```
{
  'Satuday, 31 Jan  2021': { PTM: { '7': '402 - 1' }, PT: { '7': '905 - 2' } }
}
```

When it should be like:

```
{
  'Satuday, 31 Jan  2021': { PTM: { '1': '442 - 1','2': '442 - 1',.... ,'6': '402 - 1','7': '402 - 1' }, PT: { '1': '442 - 1','2': '442 - 1',.... ,'6': '402 - 1','7': '905 - 2' } }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the url you're trying to crawl?

Comment: Why? does it matter? im looping threw tbody tr and getting the text from "td"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looping throught tbody tr and getting the text from "td"

Hem... okay. Below is just a guess...

Just reading the code without any HTML to rely on, I still have to suggest.

```
finalResult[date] = {};

$(this).find('tbody tr').each(function (i, el) {

  // That is all td for one row
  var $tds = $(this).find('td')
  
  // So that is a row counter
  var counter = i +1;

  // Now looping tds of ONE row
  $tds.each(function(index, element){

    // Retreiving the corresponding column element (for the column name)
    var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());

    if($th.text() != ""){
    
      // If not already existing, set that as an empty object
      // If undefined, it set an empty object
      // If existing, it does not change anything
      finalResult[date][$th.text()] = finalResult[date][$th.text()] || {};
      
      // The td text as an object {column+number:"text"}
      var temp = { [counter] : $(this).text()};
      
      // "merge" that new "td object" to the existing column object
      finalResult[date][$th.text()] = { ...finalResult[date][$th.text()], ...temp };
      
    }
  });
});
```

In your code, `finalResult[date][$th.text()] = { ...temp };` was just overwriting the previous object...